# MySQL Order by index still using FileSort

Tags: mysql

I have some testimonials table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testimonials` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` enum('active','test','inactive','') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  `t_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `t_order` (`t_order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;
```

And some simple task: enable manual sorting.

---

**The `SELECT` query looks:**

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT t_order, id, title, description FROM testimonials WHERE status = 'active' ORDER BY t_order DESC;
```

**The output:**

```
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |

|  1 | SIMPLE      | testimonials | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   23 | Using where; Using filesort |
```

---

`ORDER BY` uses index field, but still `EXPLAIN` shows `Using filesort`.

**Why a sort can’t be performed from an index?
Something with the query?**

Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` column shows the index used and it`s null. Using where only means you are using a [WHERE to restrict the rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html).For your query

```
ALTER TABLE testimonials ADD KEY(status,t_order )
```

is the best index,assuming you have enough rows so an index will make sense.(For very few rows a table scan is faster than an index.)

Comment: Thanks. For me, the issue was not enought rows. For more then 1000 rows MySQL uses index.